# How to execute single PreparedStatement for two querys conditions

Tags: jsp, jdbc, prepared-statement

I want that a query retrieve results according to User Number. another query retrieve by username. I did some work but in NetBeans it didn't show any errors and as by output it just stuck at first if() Condition

Help me to solve if any wrong things I did in this ...

```
<% String val_name = request.getParameter("name");
String val_number = request.getParameter("number");
String query;
if((val_name != null)&&(val_number != null)) { %>
    <h4> Use only one Column for Search </h3>
<% }
else if((val_name == null)&&(val_number == null)) { %>
    <h4> Enter any Information on above field ... </h4>
<% }
else {
    Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
    Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE","hari","root");  Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE","hari","root");
    PreparedStatement stat;
    ResultSet rs;
    if(val_number != null) {
        query= val_number;                // user Entered only Number Field ...
        String sql="SELECT * FROM EMP WHERE EMPNO= ?";
        stat=con.prepareStatement(sql);
        stat.setString(1,val_number);
        rs=stat.executeQuery();
    }
    else {
        query= val_name;  // user Entered only Name Field ...
        String sql="SELECT * FROM EMP WHERE ENAME = ?";
        stat=con.prepareStatement(sql);
        stat.setString(1,val_name);
        rs=stat.executeQuery();
    }

    try {
        if(rs!=null) {
            %>
            <br>
            <table class="gridtable" border=1 cellspan=60 cellpadding=16>
            <tr>
            <th> Emp ID </th>
            <th> Emp Name </th>
            <th> Emp Dept </th>
            <th> Emp D.o.B </th>
            <th> Show Record </th>
            <th> Record Update </th>
            <th> Compassionate </th>
            </tr>
            <%
            while(rs.next()) {
                %>
                <tr>
                <td><%= rs.getInt("EMPNO")%> </td>
                <td><%= rs.getString("ENAME") %> </td>
                <td><%= rs.getString("JOB")%> </td>
                <td><%= rs.getInt("DEPTNO")%> </td>
                <td><button><a  class="ui-button" type="button" href="/result.jsp?name="<%=name%> target="destination"> Show </a> </buton></td>
                <td><button><a  class="ui-button" type="button" href="/update.jsp?name="<%=name%> target="destination"> Update </a> </buton></td>
                <td><button><a  class="ui-button" type="button" href="/compassionate.jsp?name="<%=name%> target="destination"> Compassionate </a> </buton></td>
                </tr>
                <%
            }
        }
    }
    catch(SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    con.close();
}%>
```

Comment: **Please** don't embed JDBC code in a JSP. [Model 1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_1) is not scalable, and hasn't been widely used in industry for 15+ years.

Comment: but it is just for Testing of Small application ... [ up to 20 records ]  

okay i will follow your suggestion ... but can you given any suggestion about question ...

Comment: Define the `ResultSet` before your `if-else` chain. Also, realize that this code will be very fragile.

Comment: yeah i did that step .. and edited also ..  i can see eddited code as like you said bro

Answer (score 1):

Your `Connection`, `PreparedStatement` and `ResultSet` are all defined in your last `else` block. Move them to the top.

```
else {          
    String url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE";
    Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url,"hari","root"); 
    PreparedStatement stat;
    ResultSet rs;
```

Define the variables like

```
String val_name = request.getParameter("name"); 
String val_number = request.getParameter("number"); 
String query; 
String url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE";
Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
Connection con = null; 
PreparedStatement stat = null;
ResultSet rs = null;
```

And then set the values in your `if-else` chain.